# IIS shuts itself down. It returns 500

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have API in IIS. API works great. but when I send 40-90 queries in 10-15 seconds, API throws `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error` exception.

If I don't send the API a few queries per second it works fine.

At first my suspicion was related to SQL. Because at the same time, `table select` and `table update` operations were carried out from the same table.

### How can I prevent IIS itself from throwing 500 after a while?

Comment: Have you enabled logging and examined the site logs?

Comment: I share it @Stu I edited

Comment: The error is in the application, not in IIS, and therefore the IIS access logs aren't particularly helpful. So instead, once you start seeing the 500 errors, try to access the API via browser (turn off custom errors or do it from the web server directly to see the full message).

Comment: It doesn't throw a Yellow Screen of Death?  Do you have <customErrors mode="Off" /> set?

Comment: so what can i do? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: no. I have not got. @Duston

Comment: Obviously, please set <customErrors mode="Off" /> and send request from IIS machine itself to get error page with useful error information. And check event viewer to get more detailed error message, otherwise nobody can know what happened of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

Although the source of the error is not clearly known, manual renewal over IIS brings the API to itself. That's why an API will refresh itself exactly in per 1 minute, not Manual.

**Step 1**

İİS => Application Pools => Select own API => Advanced Settings

Like image
[image]

**Step 2**

Recycling Panel => Regular time interval => default value is 1740
[image]

Now is great Working.